# android enumerate USB application

Tags: android, usb, enumerate, accessory

I have an application that uses USB accessory.  The app is setup to auto detect the device using the intent filter when the device is plugged in and then starts the application.  My manifest follows the android development example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.switchpanel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.switchpanel.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"  >

            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter">
            </meta-data> 

                   </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I need the app to run and then enumerate(connect) to the device AFTER app is running!**

To do this I know that you need to request permission, getlist, enumerate, broadcast,... on so on.

Not completely sure how to implement all this and how the manifest (what intents to use) should be set up.

Can anyone shed some light or better yet show an example app of how this is all set up?

Answer (score 2):

FTDI offers some demo applications [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/Android_Projects.htm) that show how to establish the USB communication.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using the FTDI FT311 eval board and demo app.  THat is what I need help with.  The app works great when pluggin USB cable in, but can't get it to work when I want to run app with cable already plugged in.

Comment: The FT311 demo apps prohobit you from opening the app on your own, they will only launch when they detect a USB accessory attached and then when it is detached they close the app completely. I have realized that this was FTDI's workaround for many other pesky issues and nuiances with enumerating the USB. This is also why they did not allow for rotation in their demo app. I am currently working on figuring out fixes for some of these issues. I do know that in order to allow rotation you need to use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in the manifest xml and then...

Comment: ...use `@Override` in your main activity and override the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {super.onConfigurationCahanged(newConfig); setContentView(R.layout.yourMainActivity); }` and that will redraw the layout in the new orientation without calling onDestroy and onCreate thus you do not have to worry about enumerating the USB device again when there is a rotation.

Comment: Also, if you do want to be able to launch your app without having to plug into a USB you can add `<action android:name = "android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` and `<category android:name = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>` to you rmanifest. But this can cause issues with enumeration with certain sets of actions with the tablet.

Comment: So I have tried to add the action `ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED` to the BroadcastReceiver and this has not worked. After much searching, it seems that this action can ONLY be caught by an `intent-filter` in the manifest. It seems that this is a known issue according to [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=25703) and [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25701).

Comment: I have found that if you create a button that just calls `OpenAccessory(accessory)` with using the same `getAccessories()` found in `ResumeAccessory()` that the connection with the tablet and the FT311 will be reestablished and should work fine (I have only done minimal testing on this method so far).